# In this pattern program, why does value start to increase in star()?

Tags: c, function, if-statement, recursion

I want to print a star pattern using recursion. I went with this method, but I don't know how this program works. Can someone specifically help me understand why in the star() function, the input value starts to increase even if no such condition is given in the code?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int star(int n) 
{
   if(n>1) {
      star(n-1);
    }

    printf("* ");
}

int logic(int n) 
{
   if(n>1) {
      logic(n-1); 
       }

   star(n); 
   printf("\n");
}

int main() 
{
   int n = 3;
   logic(n);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Show the pattern you are going to display.

Comment: You have two functions that say they will return an `int` but both return nothing.

Comment: I want to simply print a star pattern. ( right triangle shaped)

Answer (score 0):

The function `star` is incorrect.

For starters, it returns nothing though its return type is not `void`.

And secondly, it can output the string `"* "` even if to pass to the function `0` or even a negative value.

The function should be declared and defined at least like:

```
void star( int n ) 
{
    if ( n > 0 ) 
    {
       printf( "* " );

       star( n - 1 );
    }
}
```

That is, if the value of the parameter `n` is a positive value

```
if ( n > 0 )
```

then the function outputs the string `"* "`

```
printf("* ");
```

and calls itself with the decreased value of the argument.

So the function will call itself recursively as many times as the passed argument stays a positive value in each recursive call.

It is the same if to rewrite the function using a loop instead of recursive calls of it itself the following way:

```
void star( int n ) 
{
    while ( n > 0 )
    {
        printf( "* " );
        n = n - 1;
    }
}
```

The function `logic` also should be rewritten as, for example:

```
void logic( int n ) 
{
    if ( n > 0 ) 
    {
        if ( n > 1 ) logic( n - 1 ); 

        star( n ); 
    }

    putchar( '\n' );
}
```

If initially the function is called with `n` equal to 0 or to a negative number then it just outputs the new line character.

Thus the function `logic`  calls itself as many times as the height of the outputted triangle (or pyramid). And in each its call it calls the function `star` to output a line of characters `"* "`.

If to call the function `logic` like:

```
logic( 5 );
```

then the output will be:

```
*
* *
* * *
* * * *
* * * * *
```

Comment: I want to specifically print this star patter using if statement only. Although there is no return, program runs perfectly and I get the same output.

Comment: @Krish I showed you  how the functions should be defined. But there is a problem if you wnat to output a  right hande triangle. In this case  you need to specifier the  width of the line and how many the symbol '*' should  be outputted.

Comment: @Krish you should take the advice from more seasoned programmers.